# Build dynamic fluent validator property selector

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm generating dynamic validation rules for fluent validator. The framework takes the rule as a parameter:

```
RuleFor(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
```

So basically a property selector with its type.

What I have now that works fine for `TProperty` known at compile time works fine:

```
private Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> GetPropertyExpression<T, TProperty>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(property, parameter);
}
```

I need a variant that can return `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>`, but with `TProperty` set at runtime.

I tried invoking my method with reflection and casting to `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>`, but it becomes null. I think I need a proper cast of the actual `TProperty` type.

Ideally, the method would take a propertyname and a `Type` argument. I'd like some pointers in the right direction here.